# Where would I ask questions related to notetaking on Obsidian?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a few questions about the note taking app Obsidian, but I'm not too sure where to ask them. I've seen some Obsidian tags on the main page Stack Overflow, but I realized those questions are more geared towards code related questions, mines are more about the app itself. Is there another suitable site?

Comment: What type of app/platform? Mobile? Desktop? Just a website?

Comment: Mobile and desktop application, not a website

Comment: Why exactly do you have questions about an ordinary application? Was the documentation or built-in help not sufficient?

Comment: Built-in help not sufficient

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Please delete & flag obsolete comments.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are referring to https://obsidian.md. This "app" is cross-platform so there are several sites where you might ask questions about it:

- [Super User](https://superuser.com) for questions about installable "apps" on computers, independently of the operative system
- [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) for some questions about using Apple devices like Mac, iPhone, and iPad, including some questions about running/using "apps" on these devices.
- [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com) for some questions about using apps for Android.
- Etc.

The complete list of sites is on https://stackexchange.com/sites. There you can learn the "site elevator pitch" / "site excerpt" of each site.